# Visual Studio 2010 Add In using Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, configuration, metadata, add-in

I'm creating an AddIn that launches a Forms-based GUI. The AddIn and the Gui are in different projects. The Gui connects to a database and utilizes EF for the ORM.

When I launch the Gui project from VS, it works great. When I publish that Gui to the vs add-ins folder and run it, it works fine. When I launch the Gui from the add-in in VS, it loads up fine, but anything that tries to hit the database fails. EF complains about the metadata files.

> Exception: The specified named
>   connection is either not found in
>   configuration, not intended to be used
>   with the EntityClient provider, or not
>   valid.
>
> at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString()

Here is the configuration in app.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="companyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=TESTDB;Initial Catalog=company;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=id;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

The only thing I can think of is that the "res://*/" portion maps differently when the starting assembly is different, but I've tried using absolute paths to the csdl/msl/ssdl files without any success.

What is different about launching the Gui from an Add-In that breaks the configuration?

Comment: Update: If I add the connectionString info into the devenv.exe.config file, then the Gui app works. So the question becomes: what is the proper way to configure the AddIn/Gui project so that the Gui doesn't have to know how it is being launched (directly, or as as AddIn)

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on a `connectionString` in a config file which you don't control. Instead, pass it explicitly when you new up your context, using the `ObjectContext` overload which takes a connection string.

Comment: I suppose that would work technically, but it isn't an advisable approach for a common assembly that gets used in a about a dozen of our projects.